# Why is saveAs failing from read-only file?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

My application uses the google realtime API to define a custom document type, and includes a feature that allows you to create a copy of a document, using the API's [document.saveAs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.Document.html#saveAs).  One purpose of this is to allow users to make and edit personal copies of document templates that have been shared with them as read-only files.  I create a new document then use saveAs to copy the realtime document into it, something like this:

```
gapi.client.drive.files.create({
    resource: {
        mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk',
        name: NEWNAME
}).then((response) => {
    MYDOCUMENT.saveAs(response.result.id);
});
```

This works perfectly with read-write files, but if the original file is read only it does not appear to save the realtime document into the new file. No error is reported but the resulting new file is empty.

Is this is a bug or known limitation, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check [Collaborators and sharing](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/collaborators) wherein it was stated that the Realtime API uses Google Drive to [manage permissions and sharing](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing).

Reading further,

> Access to files & folders is determined by an access control list (ACL). An ACL is a list of permissions that determine whether or not users can perform actions on a file such as read or write. See the [permissions guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions) for additional details about permissions and roles.

The [role](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-permissions#roles) gives these users the ability to do something to the file, like read it. As far as I've read, here are the permitted operations for read-only:

- Read the metadata (e.g. name, description) of the file or folder
- Read the content of the file
- Read the list of items in the folder

Comment: Thank you for this.  Based on the documentation, it still seems like saveAs ought to work.  I have permission to read the content of the old file and write into the new one.  So I don't see anything here that solves the puzzle.